# Ruby convert_tz using MariaDB is returning nil

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mariadb, convert-tz

When doing a regular:

```
select convert_tz(now(), "UTC", "Europe/London")
```

directly on a MariaDB server, it will produce:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| convert_tz(now(), "UTC", "Europe/London") |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 2013-03-07 16:01:32                       |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

But if done through ruby 1.8.7 or 1.9.3 width:

```
q = 'select convert_tz(now(), "UTC", "Europe/London")'
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(q)
```

it will produce:

```
"convert_tz(now(), \"UTC\", \"Europe/London\")" => nil
```

Do the same against a MySQL setup:

```
q = 'select convert_tz(now(), "UTC", "Europe/London")'
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(q)
```

results in:

```
"convert_tz(now(), \"UTC\", \"Europe/London\")" => "2013-03-07 16:05:14"
```

Now tested in MySQLWorkbench and the same bad result occurs there, null is returned instead of the converted time.

So I guess it's something in MariaDB or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to 5.5.29-MariaDB solved the problem, so I guess it was related to 5.5.28.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely missing the timezone info. You can generate this by using the `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` utility or downloading the tables from the [mysql dev site](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html).

If you're on Mac or Linux, then the following is likely to work for you (might have to update the location of your zoneinfo)

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -uroot -Dmysql
```